# Xpath expression to LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have rewrote this XPath expression to linq, but something is wrong (no element found exception).
My Html:

```
string xml = @"
<root>
   <div id=""main"">
      <div class=""content"">
         <ul>
            something
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class=""content"">
         <ul>
            something
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class=""content"">
         <ul>
            <li>
               <div>My text</div>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</root>
";
```

Xpath:

`//div[@id="main"]//div[@class="content"]/ul/li/div`

LINQ:

```
string Content =
            doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").First(x => x.GetAttributeValue("id", null) == "main")
                .Descendants("div").First(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", null) == "content")
                .Descendants("ul").First()
                .Descendants("li").First()
                .Descendants("div").First().InnerText
```

background: I have to use LINQ, because I am using Portable library.

I have already solved my problem with slightly different expression:

```
string Content =
            doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").First(x => x.GetAttributeValue("id", null) == "main")
                .Descendants("div").Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", null) == "content").ElementAt(2)
                .Descendants("ul").First()
                .Descendants("li").First()
                .Descendants("div").First().InnerText;
```

It works, but it is not same as Xpath.

So I am asking you: Does exist LINQ expression, which finds Node with InnerText without specifying exact location (like Xpath)?

Comment: And what happens when you try what you've written?

Comment: //div.. finds ALL divs with the attribute id = main; not only the 1st one...

Comment: is the original //div[@id="main"]//div[@class="content"] or //div[@id="main"]/div[@class="content"] ?

Comment: this is original //div[@id="main"]//div[@class="content"]/ul/li/div

Comment: You don't want Descendants, you want Elements - Descendants finds ALL matching children (inc grandchildren, great grandchildren, long lost step-grand children, the child of that one night stand, etc). You want only direct children, so use Elements...

Comment: With Elements it is the same as with Descendants. No Element has been found exception.

Comment: Can you use HtmlAgilityPack to parse your XML data? Or do you definetly only have Linq as an option?

Comment: It is special PCL version of HtmlAgilityPack with no Xpath option.

Comment: You say you "already solved my problem with slightly different expression" but thats the answer I gave you.

Comment: "It works, but it is not same as Xpath." - What do you mean by this? More detail needed.

Comment: Xpath is more variable. And I would prefer variability. With Xpath it is "find innertext in the structure of nodes", but with LINQ it is "get exactly one element from the structure of nodes".

Comment: LINQ .First() means get exactly one (the first one).  If that isn't what you want then you use a different expression.  I don't understand what you want to work differently.  Maybe if you posted an actual example of some input and then what you expect the output to be.

Comment: I would like to get exactly same expression like my Xpath. LINQ.First() is not correct - but I had to put there something. So maybe not every Xpath can be converted to LINQ - am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want... you are expecting the first match in the document and not all matches right?

```
string Content =
    doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("id", null) == "main")
        .Descendants("div").Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", null) == "content")
        .Elements("ul")
        .Elements("li")
        .Elements("div").First().Value;
```

In general...

> XPath '//' -> translates to LINQ .Descendants
>
> XPath '/' -> translates to LINQ .Elements

Comment: It is not possible to debug> Elements("something").Elements("something2")

Answer (score 0):

This code will retrieve the InnerText of your target div:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();

string xml = @"<root>
                  <div id=""main"">
                    <div class=""content"">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div>Test</div>
                            </li>
                        <ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </root>";

var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
var memStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

doc.Load(memStream);

var innerText =
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("id", null) == "main").First()
.Descendants("div").Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", null) == "content").First()
.Elements("ul").First()
.Elements("li").First()
.Elements("div").First().InnerText;
```

When this is run "innerText" is equal to "Test" (i.e. the innerText of the div)

Comment: This expression still does not return any element.

Comment: It does in the test I've done, I'll update my answer.

Comment: The solution you gave me is actually the same as I have in question. The elements or descendants - in this case it is the same. You can also replace where() with first().